# Инициализация локальных переменных

Tags: java

Как корректнее всего инициализировать пустые локальные переменные разных типов?
Например,

```
int a = 0;
int a = null;
String s = "";
String s = null;
List l = null;
List l = new ArrayList();
```

и т.д...

Comment: уточните вопрос, поскольку он является неполным, общим и субъективным. Я могу сказать, чтобы инициализировали всегда `null`, а Петя скажет - что цифры нужно приравнивать к нулю, а строки к "".

Comment: Вот как раз это я и хочу узнать, как **корректнее всего**  инициализировать допустим String. String s = "", String s = null или еще как то

Comment: локальные переменные нет смысла инициализировать отдельно, при попытке ее использовать без инициализации, компилятор выдаст ошибку.

Comment: @yura не знаю, что посоветуют другие - на мой взгляд, это из разряда код стайла - камелКейс или через нижнее_подчеркивание. С одним исключением, я не припомню, чтобы в java примитивам присваивали нуллы.
Обычно просто объявляется ссылка, и если в неё не засунуть значение, то компилятор сам выдает варнинги или даже не даст скомпилироваться. По поводу корректности - java строго типизированная, и по мере написания кода лично у меня не возникало подобных вопросов.

Comment: @Silento спасибо, я понял. Писал всегда null и не задавался этим вопросом, но когда пришлось это использовать при написании технического задания для трудоустройства, появились сомнения не вызовет ли это вопросов при проверке моего кода.

Comment: Вообще, в java-конвенции это не описано. Вы можете делать так, как будет удобно вам. Опять же, если противники использования `null` в коде, если сторонники, по-этому объективно что-то ответить по этому поводу не получится.

Comment: @yura понимаю. Правильно сделал, что спросил. Глупый вопрос - не заданный вопрос)

Успехов в собеседовании.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^^"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не всё так однозначно. Во-первых, стоит почитать [доки](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Во-вторых, это не всегда вопрос удобства.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Не скомпилируется с ошибкой:

> The local variable a may not have been initialized

В то же время, код ниже скомпилируется без проблем по очевидным причинам:

```
public class Main {
    static int a;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

В общем, я бы рекомендовал всегда инициализировать переменные.

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить именно об инициализации *локальных* переменных, то:

- во-первых, их всегда нужно инициализировать, иначе программа просто не скомпилируется, как и было сказано в другом ответе;
- во-вторых, переменные примитивных типов не получится инициализировать значением *null* (что тоже вполне логично);
- ну и в-третьих, самое главное - какими значениями инициализировать?
  Ответ на этот вопрос будет следующим - такими, какие имеют смысл в вашем коде. Например, если метод возвращает строку, формируемую некоторыми способом на основании параметров и при этом имеет смысл возвращаемый методом *null* - заполняйте именно таким значением, а если в любом случае должна быть какая-то строка, пусть и пустая - инициализируйте пустой строкой. Точно так же со списком: если после инициализации вы хотите его заполнять - есть ли смысл инициализировать его значением *null*? Логично предположить, что стоит всё же создать список. И т.д, можно продолжить...